# How to compare the values of 2 columns and get output into an array in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is the input dataframe:

val data = Seq(
(5416, "il", "ar", "17/02/2017"),
(5416, "ar", "us", "22/02/2017"),
(5416, "us", "au", "01/03/2017"),
(5416, "au", "sg", "03/03/2017"),
(5416, "sg", "be", "10/03/2017"),
(5416, "be", "be", "13/03/2017"),
(5416, "be", "ca", "02/04/2017"),
(5416, "ca", "ch", "16/06/2017"),
(5416, "ch", "cg", "20/06/2017"),
(5416, "cg", "at", "14/07/2017"),
(5416, "at", "no", "23/07/2017"),
).toDF("passengerId", "from", "to", "date")

[image]

We have to group by the passenger id and get the country codes from "FROM" and "TO" columns into an array. The country code in FROM and TO are in sync with each other. Data consists of passenger travelling from one country to another on different dates

Output:

[image]

**I have used the below logic:
data.groupBy("passengerId").agg(concat(collect_list(col("from")),collect_list(col("to"))).name("countries"))**

It is somehow duplicating the country codes:

["il", "ar", "us", "au", "sg", "be", "be", "ca", "ch", "cg", "at", "no", "us", "tk", "cl", "pk", "tj", "at", "sg", "nl", "tj"]

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using List, you are getting duplicates. You can eliminate duplicates by using Set. However as shown below we have to run set operation after your initial aggregation.

```
data.groupBy("id").agg(concat(collect_set("from"),collect_set("to"))).toDF("id","countries").map(_.getSeq[String](1).toSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using dataset API,
create a case class outside of the scope of this code

`case class DataClass(passengerId: Int, from: String, to: String, date: String)`

then convert the seq to dataset, use groupByKey and flatMapGroups. The solution should work well and any custom logic can be added inside the `flatMapGroups` to filter, sort and/or validate the list .

```
      import spark.implicits._

  val data =
    Seq((5416, "il", "ar", "17/02/2017"),
      (5416, "ar", "us", "22/02/2017"),
      (5416, "us", "au", "01/03/2017"),
      (5416, "au", "sg", "03/03/2017"),
      (5416, "sg", "be", "10/03/2017"),
      (5416, "be", "be", "13/03/2017"),
      (5416, "be", "ca", "02/04/2017"),
      (5416, "ca", "ch", "16/06/2017"),
      (5416, "ch", "cg", "20/06/2017"),
      (5416, "cg", "at", "14/07/2017"),
      (5416, "at", "no", "23/07/2017")
    ).map(x => DataClass(x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4)).toDS()

  data
    .groupByKey(x => x.passengerId)
    .flatMapGroups(
      (key, rowsForKey) => {
      val setOfCountries = rowsForKey
      .foldLeft[Set[String]](Set.empty)((x, y) => x + y.to + y.from) //adding  countries to set

      Option(key,setOfCountries).toList //per key a wrapper
    }).toDF("passengerId","countries")
    .show(false)

  /*
    +-----------+--------------------------------------------+
    |passengerId|countries                                   |
    +-----------+--------------------------------------------+
    |5416       |[cg, ar, us, ca, ch, at, sg, il, au, be, no]|
    +-----------+--------------------------------------------+
   */
```